# How do I separate this data using Awk?

Tags: awk, sed

```
{"name":"john","rollno":"1040.48","marks":"0.00"
```

I want to separate `rollno:1040.48` from above line using `awk`.

Comment: Did you try to get your own approach to solve this task?

Comment: It looks like partial JSON. Have you tried using `jq`?

Comment: If you want the perfect answer, you'd better explain precisely what you want to do. Do you want to capture the second element in your Json file ? Do you want to get only the element that start with rollno ? every details you will give will help us to answer. Read the How to Ask here https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the complete JSON file

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "rollno": "1040.48",
  "marks": "0.00"
}
```

(newlines are not significant), then the following will extract the data associated with the key `rollno` using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq -r '.rollno' file.json
1040.48
```

Or, with some string formatting included:

```
$ jq -r '"rollno: \(.rollno)"' file.json
rollno: 1040.48
```

The `-r` flag is to get "raw" output from `jq`, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '{"name":"john","rollno":"1040.48","marks":"0.00"' | awk -F, '{print $2}'
```

Output

```
"rollno":"1040.48"
```